# trim в Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

В Action Script 3 отсутствует функция trim - удаление пробелов и невидимых символов с левого и правого края строки. Как реализовать коротко и быстро?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static const _TRIM_PATTERN:RegExp = /^\s*|\s*$/g;

public static function trim(text:String):String
{
     return text.replace(_TRIM_PATTERN, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это неверное заявление. Фо флэш тот, который flex есть trim

```
StringUtil.trim(" my string ");
```

Если хочется самому сделать trim - то способов миллион. От перебора строки до регепса. Я бы сделал как нибудь так..

```
private static const _TRIM_PATTERN:RegExp = /^\s*|\s*$/g;

public static function trim(text:String):String {
    return text.replace(_TRIM_PATTERN, "");
}
```